# Why is an incremental increase to an integer in C causing overflow?

Tags: c, cs50, integer-overflow

I'm working through CS50 and am currently working on a small function to determine the winner(s) of an election.

```
  void print_winner(void)
    {
        int max_votes = 0;
        int num_of_winners = 0;
        string winners [] = {};
    
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        //Determine if the candidate has enough votes to be considered a winner
            if (candidates[i].votes >= max_votes) {
                //If so, increment the number of winners
                num_of_winners ++;
                //Assign the winning candidate to the winners array
                winners[i] = candidates[i].name;
                //And reset the max number of votes required to now be considered a winner
                max_votes = candidates[i].votes;
            }
           printf("number of winners  %i\n", num_of_winners);
        }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_winners; i++) {
         printf("winner  %s\n", winners[i]);
    }
        return;
    }
```

Whenever I run the function the counter seems to increment properly but on the last printout the  number is clearly wrong:

[image: Console print out]

I'm still learning C and from what I've read this sounds like either a memory allocation issue or some kind of integer overflow issue however I'm unsure what the issue is and how to fix it.

Comment: `string` isn't C.  Your array has no size, so writing to it corrupts the stack.

Comment: At first sight it looks like you increase the number of winners but not the array associated with it.

Comment: you are not allocating memory for your array of winners. . You could declare winner as `string winners [100]` or whatever the max number of winners are.

Comment: there is also a logical bug in your function. Imgine `candidates[0].votes = 1`, `cadidates[1].votes = 3`; You would  make then both winners

Comment: @MarkTolonen `string` in the context of CS50 is a `typedef` to `char *`.  Yes, it's an utter abomination that screws up a lot of C students.

Comment: Please do not add pictures of text. A simple copy&paste is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array winners has size 0 because you have initialized it like:

```
string winners [] = {};
```

Therefore there is no valid index i which would allow you to write winners[i]. Give a proper initial size to your array. Also, what exactly is 'string' in C?

Comment: Because the number of winners is not predictable it should be done dynamically. My guess is that 'string' is just a typedef of something like char*.

Comment: `candidate_count` would always be big enough as initial size

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Makes sense, I'm coming from Javascript so used to being able to define an empty array and populate it as needed, which I appreciate is antithetical to the nature of C. As other comments have pointed out string is just a typedef that CS50 provide to make things easier at first.

Answer (score 1):

C does not allow zero-length arrays, so you are relying on an extension provided by your compiler for this to be accepted at all:

> ```
>         string winners [] = {};
> ```

But that having been accepted, it is of no use to you, because the dimensions of C arrays are not adjustable.  Thus, any attempt to access an element of your array `winners` overruns its bounds, producing undefined behavior.  Data corruption such as you observe is one of the common manifestations of such UB.

Resolve the issue by declaring the array large enough for the largest case you want to support (and by rejecting larger cases explicitly), or else by allocating memory for it dynamically, and increasing the allocation when you find you need to do.